# what's the difference with hasOwnProperty and in?

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

When I have an array like `var user =  { name : 'Bob'};` what is the difference when using the following instruction?

```
localuser = user.name;
localuser = 'name' in user ? user.name : 'bob';
localuser = user.hasOwnProperty('name') ? user.name : 'bob'
```

Comment: `{ name : 'Bob'}` is an object literal. *in* returns true if a property is on an object **or** its `[[Prototype]]` chain. *hasOwnProperty* returns true only if a property is on the object itself and false if it's on the `[[Prototype]]` chain or not on the object at all.

Comment: duplicate question. read this article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999/if-key-in-object-or-ifobject-hasownpropertykey

Comment: @EveryEvery yeah you are right, I see that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example:

```
var o = { 'foo': 'bar' };

console.log('constructor' in o); // TRUE
console.log('foo' in o); // TRUE

console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('constructor')); // FALSE
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('foo')); // TRUE
```

## hasOwnProperty

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method. This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.

## in

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

Comment: Cool, but you need to explain your answer, not just post some code.