# Check existence of attribute in AngularJs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is is possible to check whether a given attribute is present in a directive, ideally using isolate scope or in a worst case scenario the attributes object.

With a directive that looked something like this `<project status></project>`, I want to conditionally render a status icon, but only if the status attribute is present.

```
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  scope: {
    status: '@'
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.status === 'undefined'
  }
}
```

Ideally, it would be bound straight to the scope, so that it could be used in the template. However, the bound variable's value is **undefined**. The same goes for `&` **read-only** and `=` **two-way** bindings.

I know that it's trivially solved by adding a `<project status='true'></project>`, but for directives that I will use frequently, I'd rather not have to. (XHTML validity, is not an issue).

Comment: I know you mentioned it, but just wondering - did you try something like `"status" in attrs` and see what that evaluation is?

Comment: isn't "@" a one way text binding passed to the directive? so scope.status should be the text reading 'true', so long as you pass a variable into the directive as <code><project status="{{myScopeVariable}}"></project></code>

Comment: When you specify scope as an object like above, the directive creates a new isolate Scope which doesn't inherit properties from parent scope. Instead use scope: true to create a new scope (with access to parent scope properties), or scope: false to have directive use parent scope. Is that what you're asking? I don't quite get your question...

Comment: Also the code in your link function is just a boolean expression. Did you mean to include that in an IF statement?

Comment: `scope.status === 'undefined'` <== doesn't do anything all by itself. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The way to do this is to check for the existence of the attributes within the link function's attrs parameter, and assign this to variables within your directive's isolate scope.

```
scope:{},
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  scope.status = 'status' in attrs;
},
```

This should work without having to use an if statement within your link function.

Answer (score 19):

The way to do what you want is by looking at the attribute object in the link function:

```
link: 
  function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if("status" in attrs)
       //do something
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

To Check for attributes when using angular 1.5+ components you can use the $postLink lifecycle hook and the $element service like this:

```
constructor(private $element) {}

$postLink() {
  if(!this.$element.attr('attr-name')){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `attrs` value is type of javascript `object`. To check attribute existence we can also using `hasOwnProperty()` method instead `in` keyword.

So, it could be :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var is_key_exist = attrs.hasOwnProperty('status');//Will return true if exist
}
```

You can read further the difference between `in` keyword and `hasOwnProperty()` method at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999/if-key-in-object-or-ifobject-hasownpropertykey)