# How to test the existence of an attribute in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to enable a button based on whether there's the atribute `editable` in the directive:

Editable:

```
  <table-list items="users" editable></table-list>
```

Non-editable:

```
  <table-list items="users"></table-list>
```

I tried this:

```
 .directive('tableList', function ($attr) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<a ng-if="editable" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Add to group</a>' +
    '<table class="table table-stripped">' +
    '<thead>' +
      '<tr>' +
        '<th>#</th>' +
        '<th>Name</th>' +
        '<th>Users</th>' +
        '<th>Buildings</th>' +
        '<th>Created at</th>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</thead>' +
    '<tbody>' +
      '<tr ng-repeat="item in items">' +
        '<th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" value="0"></th>' +
        '<td><a href="#/groups/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a></td>' +
        '<td>_</td>' +
        '<td>_</td>' +
        '<td>_</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</tbody>' +
      '</table>',
      scope: {
    items: "=",
    editable: "="
      },
```

But the button isn't showing.

What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check existence of attribute in Angular Directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811734/check-existence-of-attribute-in-angular-directive)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rely on a presence of the attribute only (even if it is set to `false`), you can check if it is defined with the `$attrs` in the link function:

```
scope: {
  items: "="
},
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
  $scope.editable = $attrs.editable !== undefined;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1wkua60/2/).

However, this will not be reactive (i.e. if you add the attribute in runtime, directive won't show the button). You might use [`$attrs.$observe()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929794/angular-directive-attrs-observe) if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `true`:

```
<table-list items="users" editable="true"></table-list>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L1wkua60/)

Answer (score 1):

When getting an attribute and setting it to the scope like that you're setting the value. And your `editable`-attribute has no value. If you'd do `<table-list items="users" editable="true"></table-list>` it would work better.

And in the directive you could probably use `@` instead of `=` for the attribute.

This will set the editable property on the scope to the string "true", if you want it to be a boolean you might need some logic in the link function