# hasOwnProperty when to use, and when not needed?

Tags: javascript

It is recommended to always use hasOwnProperty, but in many cases this is not needed. 
For example consider the following code:

```
var object = JSON.parse(somejsontext);
for(var prop in object) {
   console.log(object[prop]);
}
```

I know in this case that `prop` is part of the object, it is explict define by the `for..in`.

But according to MOZ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty we should use it to avoid iterating over non-enumarable props, with this example:

```
var buz = {
  fog: 'stack'
};

for (var name in buz) {
  if (buz.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    console.log('this is fog (' + name + ') for sure. Value: ' + buz[name]);
  }
  else {
    console.log(name); // toString or something else
  }
}
```

**But testing this code actually, never goes to the else.**

So when does make sense the use of `hasOwnProperty` ?

UPDATE: Considering the choosen answer, we can safetly avoid the use of hasOwnProperty in this cases:
- `Object` js has not been extended by any javascript library or by our code
- `Object` is a simple code that we have control on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999/if-key-in-object-or-ifobject-hasownpropertykey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem arises when a *prototype* includes enumerable properties that your code did not anticipate. For example, suppose this ran just before your example:

```
Object.prototype.foobar = "hello";
```

In this case, iterating over `buz` would include the enumerable `foobar` prototype property. This `hasOwnProperty` pattern allows your code to differentiate between properties that are *directly* on the object, versus properties that are inherited from a prototypal ancestor.

The problem is not "enumerating over non-enumerable properties" (that's by definition not possible, unless you explicitly get them via `getOwnPropertyNames` for each level of the prototype hierarchy), but rather enumerating over inherited properties. This is a concern when using libraries that may add enumerable properties to high-level prototypes, exactly as I have illustrated above.

If you want to add a property to a prototype without causing that property to be enumerated, you can make a non-enumerable property with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "foobar", {
    value: "hello",
    enumerable: false,
    writeable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Such a property would *not* appear in a `for..in` loop on `buz` (or in a `for..in` loop directly on `Object.prototype`, either).

Comment: yes but it would make no sense when having the control of you code, ( hoping that a library does not have extend the prototype of a basic object )

Comment: @albanx Many libraries extend native objects heavily, even `Object.prototype` might be extended.

Comment: But in the mozilla example why it does not itarete through the toString method. .

Comment: @albanx Because `Object.prototype.toString` is not enumerable; see that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, "toString")` returns a descriptor object with `enumerable: false`.

Comment: @albanx Edited with more on non-enumerable properties.

Comment: so definitively we should use hasOwnProperty only when we are sure that the Object has not been extended.