# How does this Javascript one-liner function work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var hasAll = Object.keys(obj1).every(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.bind(obj2));
```

This code I have taken is from a solution to [Best way to Check a JavaScript Object has all the keys of another JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814687/best-way-to-check-a-javascript-object-has-all-the-keys-of-another-javascript-obj)

Comment: Do you ask the logic of the functions step-by-step?

Comment: @vahdet this implementation i understood var hasAll = Object.keys(obj1).every(key => obj2.hasOwnProperty(key )); But the one mentioned in question how its similar to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It borrows [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) from the prototype of [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/) and uses `bj2` as `this` object with binding ([`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

The result is a function, which can be used as callback.

Comment: Is it similar to this implementation var hasAll = Object.keys(obj1).every(key => obj2.hasOwnProperty.bind(key ));

Comment: no, because you bind the key and get a function with no use. `bind` returns a fucntion which is always truthy. so no real check is happening.

Comment: oh my bad! what if i remove the bind. then?

Comment: then it should work, because you have an object `obj2` and a function for checking.