# Check if object contains all keys in array

Tags: javascript

How can I most succinctly check if an object contains ALL of the keys specified in an array?

For example:

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar"];

var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: "hello"
};

magic_function(arr, obj); // return true, all keys from array exist


var obj2 = {
  foo: 12,
  bar: "hi",
  test: "hey"
};

magic_function(arr, obj2); // return true, all keys from array exist,
                           // keys not specified in array don't matter


var obj3 = {
  foo: 5
};

magic_function(arr, obj3); // return false, "bar" is missing
```

Comment: Where is the `magic_function`?

Comment: @Satpal That's what OP is asking.

Comment: Yet another code service?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I was egging OP to atleast share pseudo code . As he has already asked 70+ question rather than just requesting complete code. Totally agree with _K. Daniek_ comment

Answer (score 31):

This should do it:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar"];

const obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: "hello"
};

const hasAllKeys = arr.every(item => obj.hasOwnProperty(item));

console.log(hasAllKeys);
```

[`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) returns `true` if the passed function returns `true` for **every** item in the array.
[`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: If `obj` additionally has `baz = 'test'`, this will fail- so it's not inclusive that the keys and the array match perfectly

Comment: @MattFletcher: This code only checks if all the key in the array are present on the object. It does not care about extra keys, as the original question explicitly demonstrated to be a requirement. This was never meant to be a perfect one-on-one match.

Comment: I know, I just thought I'd highlight it for anyone else looking for exact key matching

Answer (score 9):

You could iterate the array and check for the key with [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

> The `in` operator returns `true` if the specified property is in the specified object.

The difference between `in` operator and [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is, `in` checks all properties, even the ones from the prototype, like `toString` (as in the example) and `Object#hasOwnProperty` checks only own properties, without the properties from the prototypes.

```js
function checkKeys(keys, object) {
    return keys.every(function (key) {
        return key in object;
    });
}

function checkOwnKeys(keys, object) {
    return keys.every(function (key) {
        return object.hasOwnProperty(key);
    });
}

var arr = ["foo", "bar", "toString"],
    obj = { foo: 1, bar: "hello" };

console.log(checkKeys(arr, obj));                // true
console.log(checkOwnKeys(arr, obj));             // false
console.log(checkOwnKeys(["foo", "bar"], obj));  // true
```

Comment: I think it'd be useful to mention the [difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999/if-key-in-object-or-ifobject-hasownpropertykey) between `in` and `hasOwnProperty`. Specifically: _"The in operator returns true for properties in the prototype chain."_ Still, valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can check in the following way

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar"];

const obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: "hello"
};

const hasAllKeys = label => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, label);

console.log(arr.every(item => hasAllKeys(item)));
```