# Basic Data Structures: Check if an Object has a Property

Tags: javascript, boolean, hasownproperty

I've been having some trouble with the Free Code Camp lesson on checking if an object has certain properties.

In this lesson, we're supposed to use `hasOwnProperty()` to check if the `users` object contains `Alan`, `Jeff`, `Sarah`, and `Ryan`. If **all** of the users are present, then return `true`, otherwise, if any of those users are missing, then the code needs to return `false`.

I've been trying for over hour and this is kind of where I've ended up, but I can't quite figure out how to get the code to return `false` when one of the names is removed. I tend to overthink my code, so I might be thinking about it too hard.

Thanks in advance! And sorry if something like this has been asked before. I wasn't able to find anything.

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(obj) {
  // change code below this line
  for (let name in users) {
    if (name === 'Alan' && 'Jeff' && 'Sarah' && 'Ryan') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  // change code above this line
}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

Comment: start a counter at 0, add 1 when name is Alan, Jeff, Sarah or Ryan. Then when loop ends check if counter is equal to 4

Comment: apart from the incorrect condition in your if statement, your code returns false when i run it in the developer console without the return statements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the properties. You should loop through the array of names you're looking for.

```js
function isEveryoneHere(obj) {
  // change code below this line
  for (let name of required) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
  // change code above this line
}

let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};
let users2 = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Jane: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

const required = ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Sarah', 'Ryan'];

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
console.log(isEveryoneHere(users2));
```

Comment: This one is really simple and easy to understand! I appreciate the second array to show how the function reacts when one of the parameters isn't present. Thanks! quick question, since the lesson didn't really explain much: why do you need the '!' in `!obj`?

Comment: That's the "not" operator. It returns false when the required name is *not* present.

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through each person, and if the value is good `continue` if not `return false`. If we make it to the end of the loop we return `true`.

```js
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(obj) {
  // change code below this line
  for (let name in obj) {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(name) || !obj[name].online){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
  // change code above this line
}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go. There are many ways to do it but this was an elegant solution. I chopped the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439885/check-if-object-contains-all-keys-in-array).

```
let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(obj) {
  // change code below this line
  var arr = ["Alan", "Jeff", "Sarah", "Ryan"];
  var hasAllKeys = arr.every(function(item){
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(item);
  });
  return hasAllKeys;
  // change code above this line
}

isEveryoneHere(users);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really similar to another person's answer which passed my test. I like the simplicity in this answer. Thanks very much for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

In the example, the statement "Alan" in users returns 'true'. Why can't you do something like:

'Alan' in users && 'Sarah' in users && 'Jeff' in users...etc.

??

Answer (score 0):

The for in loops through each property name and stores in an array. If the obj being passed does not have the property of the array(name) returns false.

```
let required = [];
for (let user in users){
  required.push(user);
}
function isEveryoneHere(obj) {
  // change code below this line
  for (let name of required) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
  // change code above this line
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
    let users = {
  Alan: {
    age: 27,
    online: true
  },
  Jeff: {
    age: 32,
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    age: 48,
    online: true
  },
  Ryan: {
    age: 19,
    online: true
  }
};

function isEveryoneHere(obj) {

if(users.hasOwnProperty('Alan', 'Jeff','Sarah','Ryan')){
  return true;
}
  return false;

}

console.log(isEveryoneHere(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this and it works:

```
function isEveryoneHere(obj) {
  // Only change code below this line
  let filter = ['Alan', 'Jeff', 'Sarah', 'Ryan'];
  let result = true;
  filter.forEach(
    (u) => {
      if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(u)){
        result = false;
      }
    }    
  );     
  return result;
  // Only change code above this line
}
```