# Possible to update the field in below datastructure in firestore database using cloud funct

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a datastructure in the form of object structure . [![enter image description here][1]][1]

> ```
> {
>   Invite1
>   {
>      Amount: 10,
>      PhoneNumber:9876543210,
>      Status:"Pending"
>   }
>   Invite2
>   {
>      Amount: 20,
>      PhoneNumber:1234566789,
>      Status:"Pending"
>   }
> }
> ```

I have a condition when whose Invite(1,2,3) PhoneNumber  matches with other document that invitee need to update the field as ***Status = true***
When I try to update a field as **Status = true** It is updating at the end of the document.
Mycode need to update

```
var dbref = db1.collection('deyaPayUsers').doc(sendauthid).collection('Split').doc(sendauthid).collection('SentInvitations').doc(senderautoid);
var msg1 = receiverph + "" + status + " to pay $" + document.Amount;
var fulldoc = dbref.get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            console.log('No such document');
        } else {
            console.log('Document data :', doc.data());
            d1 = doc.data();
            console.log("d1 is" + d1);
            for (var k in d1) {
                var p = d1[k].PhoneNumber;
                console.log("ivitees phone" + p);
                if (receiverph == p) // Here the condition is true of the invite phoneNumber then need to update
                {
                    console.log("p" + PhoneNumber);


                    console.log("the phonenumber matches");
```

> var updated = dbref.update({"Status":status});// Here It is updating
>   at the endof the document

***other Method to update***

d1.Status = status; // In d1 I have the document data
 var setdata = dbref.set(d1);

Please if their is any approach help with me.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the code you have already written and where you are encountering problems/errors. Also, is the field Status in the same document than the 3 InviteX fields?

Comment: I need to update the status in any invite if my condition is true. K I will share my piece of code

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code. When you say that "updating at the end of the document" is not what you are looking for, it means that you want to update each Invite field in the document. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that you would like to update each InviteXX item in the document, here is a code that will work (I've kept the main part of your code):

```
var dbref = db1.collection('deyaPayUsers').doc(sendauthid).collection('Split').doc(sendauthid).collection('SentInvitations').doc(senderautoid);
var msg1 = receiverph +"" + status +" to pay $"+document.Amount;
const fulldoc = dbref.get()
    .then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            //console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

            const inviteUpdate = {};  //An object that we will update by looping over the InviteXX objects of the document

            const d1 = doc.data();
            //console.log("d1 is" + d1);

            for (let key in d1) {
                if (d1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    const p = d1[key].PhoneNumber;
                    //console.log(key);
                    //console.log("invitees phone " + p);
                    if (receiverph === p) // Here the condition is true of the invite phoneNumber then need to update
                    {
                        inviteUpdate[key + '.status'] = true;
                        //The key point is here: we define the object field with a mix of dot notation and []
                    }
                }
            }

            return dbref.update(inviteUpdate);

        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
            throw "No such document"
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

Note that:

1. You should return a promise in your Cloud Function. I don't have the full code of your function but probably you will return `fulldoc`. (You may have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=2s)
2. I don't know how do you get/initialize receiverph
3. You may use const or let instead of var in a Cloud Function (JavaScript ES6+)

Comment: @vijju So how went your check?

Comment: if (d1.hasOwnProperty(key))  what it do at this line

Comment: @vijju See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999/if-key-in-object-or-ifobject-hasownpropertykey?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa. I would say that in this specific case it is not absolutely mandatory but more a best practice to apply.

Comment: @vijju Were you able to progress on this problem?

Comment: Hey I  got the solution

Comment: what is the difference of my answer and yours. Can  u justify me . Because I am trying this from 1 week

Comment: @vijju loop over the invitees and for each one, add the field. In other words don't filter with `if (receiverph === p)`