# javascript differences between if (value in item) and if (item.hasOwnProperty(value))

Tags: javascript

I just want to know if those 2 statements are equals or not, JS makes me mad and its behavior remain too esoteric. Within my app, it occurs some strange results ...

`value in item` and `item.hasOwnProperty(value)`

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632999/if-key-in-object-or-ifobject-hasownpropertykey

Answer (score 1):

`in` also looks up the prototype tree while `hasOwnProperty` only checks the object itself.

Comment: Oh ? Thanks for answer, so my problem should come from the prototype .. I'll check that, thanks again :)